# Reported bandwidth usage differs between iproute2 and ifconfig

Tags: linux, monitoring, bandwidth, ifconfig, iproute2

My group has a server set up to image our workstations using [FOG](http://fogproject.org). I was a bit curious to see how much bandwidth we were using. When I run `ifconfig eth0`, the TX/RX lines read

```
RX packets:166949376 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:350126730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:31757576798 (29.5 GiB)  TX bytes:458006556301 (426.5 GiB)
```

But when I run `ip -s link show eth0`, the equivalent output is

```
RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
1693647583 166958818 0       0       0       18979  
TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
2741139294 350136238 0       0       0       0
```

Which corresponds to a TX/RX of about 1.8/2.6 GiB. What is causing the discrepancy between the values reported by `iproute2` and `ifconfig`? Is there some sort of integer overflow for `iproute2`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find some `iproute2` documentation which shed some light on the issue.

Thanks to [Jonathan Ross's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/257895/reported-bandwidth-usage-differs-between-iproute2-and-ifconfig/257896#257896), I learned that `ifconfig` pulls its data from `/proc/net/dev`. In the [`iproute2` docs,](https://serverfault.com/questions/257895/reported-bandwidth-usage-differs-between-iproute2-and-ifconfig/257896#257896) it appears that the bandwidth counter in `iproute2` "wraps when the maximal length of the natural data type on the architecture is exceeded".

It's evident that `iproute2` uses a 32-bit integer to store this info, as this is a 64-bit system. The bandwidth counter would then wrap at 4 GiB.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways of pulling traffic stats from the system with libraries or from the kernel, one being `cat /proc/net/dev`. I'd check that file for comparison.

Slightly OT: apparently you can reset `ifconfig` counters with loadable NIC kernel drivers but not built-in drivers.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know where ``ifconfig`` pulls its data. The ``/proc/net/dev`` file lists the proper bandwidth usage (TX/RX of 29.5/426.5 GiB). I found some ``iproute2`` documentation which answered my question.